# Insert vector graphics from Matlab to Word 2013

Tags: matlab, pdf, vector, ms-word, eps

i know its a often discussed topic. But i haven't found any solution for me. I have some plots, which i need to import in Word 2013 afterwards the docx is saved as pdf.

The problem is:

If the plot gets saved (with the function print() ) as .eps or emf and imported in Word, the downsampled placeholder of the graphics look pretty poor and the graphics in pdf are no vector grapic anymore. They do get turned into a bitmap and by zooming in a bit, one can see the pixels. If i use Edit -> Copy Figure in the Matlab figure and paste it in Word, i get a nice graphic in Word as well as a nice vector based graphic in the pdf file.

Is there a way, to save a figure to a file and import it to Word and have the same quality like i have by copy and paste? What is the difference between these methods?

Thank you for your help.

Rafael

Comment: save it as png?

Comment: i'd like to have a vector based graphic not a bitmap.

Comment: ahh, the use LaTeX :P. Hope you get help with this. ;)

Comment: This is an issue with Word's EPS rendering engine. Typically we will use the .eps file but when you print the document to a PDF (using the adobe printer) the vector graphics remain vector graphics.

Comment: The simplest way is to use "inkscape": Import your image-file there and store it as a vector based graphic